# Why are animations triggered by calling .animate() on TYPE UIView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

Here's something I don't find to be logical:

When animating the property of a `UIView` (in this case `mainView`) the funciton is called on the generic type, instead of on the specific Instance of `UIView`

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: flashDuration, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.allowUserInteraction, animations: {
        self.mainView.backgroundColor = self.black
    }, completion: nil)
```

This is quite useful, because I can now animate different instances of `UIView` in the same place, **but how is it possible to call a function on a generic type?**

I have never came across this anywhere else in Swift.

Comment: It isn't a "generic type". It is a class method. Both Objective-C and Swift have class methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what exactly happens under the hood because UIKit isn't open-source

Before the block-based UIView animation methods were introduced, animating views looked like this, and those methods are actually still available:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
myView.center = CGPointMake(300, 300);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Knowing this, we could implement our own block-based animation method like this:

```
(void)my_animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration animations:(void (^)(void))animations
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
    animations();
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

The actual animation is performed by Core Animation, which works at the layer level – each UIView has a backing CALayer instance that is responsible for animations and compositing, while the view mostly just handles touch events and coordinate system conversions.

I won't go into detail here on how Core Animation works, you might want to read the [Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for that. Essentially, it's a system to animate changes in a layer tree, without explicitly calculating every keyframe (and it's actually fairly difficult to get intermediate values out of Core Animation, you usually just specify from and to values, durations, etc. and let the system take care of the details).

Comment: That is a bit confusing, because you're explaining a Swift question with Obj-C code. Also I still don't understand how one can call a method on a type rather than an instance of a type.

Comment: There's a very thin line between swift and objc NOW , 99% of the api is easily convertible (to and from), it makes no difference. The concept remains the same.